ReactiveUI receive notification of property change in element of child collection
I have a viewmodel class which has an observable collection of a child viewmodel class. I want to the parent VM to know when a certain property of the child VM changes (due to user input) and then operate on that instance.  If I was directly implementing INotifyPropertyChanged I might implement something like this:
public class ChildVM : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  private string _fieldOfInterest;
  private string _commentary;

  public string FieldOfInterest{
    get { return _fieldOfInterest; }
    set {
      if (_fieldOfInterest != value) {
        _fieldOfInterest = value;
        NotifyListeners();
      }
    }
  }

  public string Commentary {
    get { return _commentary; }
    set {
      if (_commentary != value) {
        _commentary = value;
        NotifyListeners();
      }
    }
  }

  private void NotifyListeners([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "") {
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}


public class ParentVM : INotifyPropertyChanged {
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  // For its own properties not relevant here
  public ObservableCollection<ChildVM> Children { get; set; }

  public ParentVM () {
    Children = new ObservableCollection<ChildVM>();
    for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
      var child = new ChildVM();
      child.PropertyChanged += HandleChildPropertyChanged;
      Children.Add(child);
    }
  }

  private void HandleChildPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(ChildVM.FieldOfInterest)) {
      var changedChild = (sender as ChildVM);
      changedChild.SetCommentary("You entered: " + changedChild.FieldOfInterest);
    }
  }
}

Most of XAML for control which has ParentVM instance as its DataContext:
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Commentary}" />
          <TextBox Text="{Binding FieldOfInterest}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>

So, how do I achieve comparable functionality with ReactiveUI?  Something involving WhenAny or Subscribe, I assume?  So far my VMs look like:
  public abstract class ViewModelBase : ReactiveObject {
  }

  public class ChildVM : ViewModelBase {
    private string _fieldOfInterest;
    private string _commentary;

    public string FieldOfInterest {
      get => _fieldOfInterest;
      set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _fieldOfInterest, value);
    }

    public string Commentary {
      get => _commentary;
      set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _commentary, value);
    }
  }

  public class ParentVM : ViewModelBase {
    public ObservableCollection<ChildVM> Children { get; set; }

    public ParentVM () {
      Children = new ObservableCollection<ChildVM>();
      for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
        var child = new ChildVM();
        // TODO: handler assignment the RxUI way
        Children.Add(child);
      }
    }
  }


Thanks…
